# "invalid_client" Error in Django OAuth Toolkit Despite Following Documentation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, oauth

I'm encountering an "invalid_client" error when attempting to obtain an OAuth token using Django OAuth Toolkit. I've been meticulously following the [official documentation](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html#step-4-get-your-token-and-use-your-api) but I am unable to resolve the issue.

> Error Details:
>
> Error Response: {"error": "invalid_client"}

Server Log:

> Unauthorized: /o/token/ [11/Jan/2024 20:13:37] "POST /o/token/ HTTP/1.1" 401 27

Steps Taken:

- Repeated documentation steps: I've carefully followed the documentation's instructions from scratch multiple times.
- Verified credentials: I've double-checked the client ID, client secret, username, and password for accuracy and typos.
- Inspected request details: I've examined the cURL command and request details to ensure they align with the server's expectations.

Specific context:

OAuth Server/Library: Django OAuth Toolkit

Relevant code snippet:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>" -u"<client_id>:<client_secret>" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

- Common pitfalls: Are there any common mistakes or configuration issues that might lead to this error in Django OAuth Toolkit?
- Troubleshooting suggestions: What additional diagnostic steps can I take to pinpoint the root cause?
- Server-side considerations: Are there any server-side settings or logs I should examine?

Comment: verify that `authorization_grant_type` is set to `password` on your `Application` model (ie. `Application.authorization_grant_type == 'password'`

by default it is set to `authorization-code`

Comment: Hi Dash,

Thanks for the tip! Checked authorization_grant_type in oauth2_provider app (no custom apps installed). It's set to "password", so configuration seems correct. Still getting "invalid_client" error. Any further suggestions based on this? Thanks again for your help!

Best regards

Comment: if you recently upgraded to major version `2.x` you may be receiving errors related to these changes:
https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id2